# Multiple input, single output with tensorrt c++ api

Tags: c++, tensorrt

I have a model which is made of 3 inputs and 1 output. I generated the TRT engine from my onnx model as shown below

```
int main() {

    int maxBatchSize = 32;

    nvinfer1::IBuilder* builder = nvinfer1::createInferBuilder(gLogger);
    const auto explicitBatch = 1U << static_cast<uint32_t>(nvinfer1::NetworkDefinitionCreationFlag::kEXPLICIT_BATCH);
    nvinfer1::INetworkDefinition* network = builder->createNetworkV2(explicitBatch);

    nvonnxparser::IParser* parser = nvonnxparser::createParser(*network, gLogger);


    parser->parseFromFile("model3.onnx", 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < parser->getNbErrors(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << parser->getError(i)->desc() << std::endl;
    }

    builder->setMaxBatchSize(maxBatchSize);
    nvinfer1::IBuilderConfig* config = builder->createBuilderConfig();
    config->setMaxWorkspaceSize(1 << 20);
    nvinfer1::ICudaEngine* engine = builder->buildEngineWithConfig(*network, *config);

    parser->destroy();
    network->destroy();
    config->destroy();
    builder->destroy();

    nvinfer1::IHostMemory* serializedModel = engine->serialize();

    std::ofstream engine_file("model.engine");

    engine_file.write((const char*)serializedModel->data(), serializedModel->size());

    serializedModel->destroy();
    return 0;
}
```

How can I perform inference since I have multiple inputs? In the Nvidia guide, only the scenario for single input single output is given.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the files that are shipped with the `TensorRT` installations.
Check out the `C:\TensorRT\samples\common` directory. Take a look at the `buffers.h` header file.
Take a look at the MNIST example in the same directory which uses the `buffers.h`.
The `buffers.h` file takes care of multiple inputs or outputs.
It creates a BufferManager to deal with those inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some code snippets to get you started. For a full working example for an implementation which works for single / multiple inputs and single / multiple outputs, check out [this](https://github.com/cyrusbehr/tensorrt-cpp-api) project.

Here is the relevant portion of code when you read the engine file into memory. You want to dynamically determine the number of inputs and outputs and allocate enough GPU memory to store the buffers.

```cpp
    // Storage for holding the input and output buffers
    // This will be passed to TensorRT for inference
    m_buffers.resize(m_engine->getNbBindings());

    // Create a cuda stream
    cudaStream_t stream;
    checkCudaErrorCode(cudaStreamCreate(&stream));


    // Allocate GPU memory for input and output buffers
    m_outputLengthsFloat.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < m_engine->getNbBindings(); ++i) {
        if (m_engine->bindingIsInput(i)) {
            auto inputBindingDims = m_engine->getBindingDimensions(i);

            // Allocate memory for the input
            // Allocate enough to fit the max batch size (we could end up using less later)
            checkCudaErrorCode(cudaMallocAsync(&m_buffers[i], m_options.maxBatchSize * inputBindingDims.d[1] * inputBindingDims.d[2] * inputBindingDims.d[3] * sizeof(float), stream));

            // Store the input dims for later use
            m_inputDims.emplace_back(inputBindingDims.d[1], inputBindingDims.d[2], inputBindingDims.d[3]);
        } else {
            // The binding is an output
            uint32_t outputLenFloat = 1;
            auto outputDims = m_engine->getBindingDimensions(i);

            for (int j = 1; j < outputDims.nbDims; ++j) {
                // We ignore j = 0 because that is the batch size, and we will take that into account when sizing the buffer
                outputLenFloat *= outputDims.d[j];
            }

            m_outputLengthsFloat.push_back(outputLenFloat);
            // Now size the output buffer appropriately, taking into account the max possible batch size (although we could actually end up using less memory)
            checkCudaErrorCode(cudaMallocAsync(&m_buffers[i], outputLenFloat * m_options.maxBatchSize * sizeof(float), stream));
        }
    }
```

And here is a sample implementation of the actual inference function:

```
bool Engine::runInference(const std::vector<std::vector<cv::cuda::GpuMat>> &inputs, std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<float>>>& featureVectors,
                          const std::array<float, 3>& subVals, const std::array<float, 3>& divVals, bool normalize) {
    // First we do some error checking
    if (inputs.empty() || inputs[0].empty()) {
        std::cout << "===== Error =====" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Provided input vector is empty!" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    const auto numInputs = m_inputDims.size();
    if (inputs.size() != numInputs) {
        std::cout << "===== Error =====" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Incorrect number of inputs provided!" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Ensure the batch size param was set correctly
    if (!m_options.doesSupportDynamicBatchSize) {
        if (inputs[0].size() > 1) {
            std::cout << "===== Error =====" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Model does not support running batch inference!" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Please only provide a single input" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
    }

    const auto batchSize = static_cast<int32_t>(inputs[0].size());
    // Make sure the same batch size was provided for all inputs
    for (size_t i = 1; i < inputs.size(); ++i) {
        if (inputs[i].size() != static_cast<size_t>(batchSize)) {
            std::cout << "===== Error =====" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "The batch size needs to be constant for all inputs!" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Create the cuda stream that will be used for inference
    cudaStream_t inferenceCudaStream;
    checkCudaErrorCode(cudaStreamCreate(&inferenceCudaStream));

    // Preprocess all the inputs
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numInputs; ++i) {
        const auto& batchInput = inputs[i];
        const auto& dims = m_inputDims[i];

        auto &input = batchInput[0];
        if (input.channels() != dims.d[0] ||
            input.rows != dims.d[1] ||
            input.cols != dims.d[2]) {
            std::cout << "===== Error =====" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Input does not have correct size!" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Execpted: (" << dims.d[1] << ", " << dims.d[2] << ", "
                      << dims.d[3] << ")" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Got: (" << input.channels() << ", " << input.rows << ", " << input.cols << ")" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Ensure you resize your input image to the correct size" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }

        nvinfer1::Dims4 inputDims = {batchSize, dims.d[0], dims.d[1], dims.d[2]};
        m_context->setBindingDimensions(i, inputDims); // Define the batch size

        // Copy over the input data and perform the preprocessing
        cv::cuda::GpuMat gpu_dst(1, batchInput[0].rows * batchInput[0].cols * batchSize, CV_8UC3);

        size_t width = batchInput[0].cols * batchInput[0].rows;
        for (size_t img = 0; img < batchInput.size(); img++) {
            std::vector<cv::cuda::GpuMat> input_channels{
                    cv::cuda::GpuMat(batchInput[0].rows, batchInput[0].cols, CV_8U, &(gpu_dst.ptr()[0 + width * 3 * img])),
                    cv::cuda::GpuMat(batchInput[0].rows, batchInput[0].cols, CV_8U, &(gpu_dst.ptr()[width + width * 3 * img])),
                    cv::cuda::GpuMat(batchInput[0].rows, batchInput[0].cols, CV_8U,
                                     &(gpu_dst.ptr()[width * 2 + width * 3 * img]))
            };
            cv::cuda::split(batchInput[img], input_channels);  // HWC -> CHW
        }

        cv::cuda::GpuMat mfloat;
        if (normalize) {
            // [0.f, 1.f]
            gpu_dst.convertTo(mfloat, CV_32FC3, 1.f / 255.f);
        } else {
            // [0.f, 255.f]
            gpu_dst.convertTo(mfloat, CV_32FC3);
        }

        // Apply normalizations
        cv::cuda::subtract(mfloat, cv::Scalar(subVals[0], subVals[1], subVals[2]), mfloat, cv::noArray(), -1);
        cv::cuda::divide(mfloat, cv::Scalar(divVals[0], divVals[1], divVals[2]), mfloat, 1, -1);

        auto *dataPointer = mfloat.ptr<void>();

        checkCudaErrorCode(cudaMemcpyAsync(m_buffers[i], dataPointer,
                                           mfloat.cols * mfloat.rows * mfloat.channels() * sizeof(float),
                                           cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice, inferenceCudaStream));
    }

    // Ensure all dynamic bindings have been defined.
    if (!m_context->allInputDimensionsSpecified()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Error, not all required dimensions specified.");
    }

    // Run inference.
    bool status = m_context->enqueueV2(m_buffers.data(), inferenceCudaStream, nullptr);
    if (!status) {
        return false;
    }

    // Copy the outputs back to CPU
    featureVectors.clear();

    for (int batch = 0; batch < batchSize; ++batch) {
        // Batch
        std::vector<std::vector<float>> batchOutputs{};
        for (int32_t outputBinding = numInputs; outputBinding < m_engine->getNbBindings(); ++outputBinding) {
            // We start at index m_inputDims.size() to account for the inputs in our m_buffers
            std::vector<float> output;
            auto outputLenFloat = m_outputLengthsFloat[outputBinding - numInputs];
            output.resize(outputLenFloat);
            // Copy the output
            checkCudaErrorCode(cudaMemcpyAsync(output.data(), static_cast<char*>(m_buffers[outputBinding]) + (batch * sizeof(float) * outputLenFloat), outputLenFloat * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, inferenceCudaStream));
            batchOutputs.emplace_back(std::move(output));
        }
        featureVectors.emplace_back(std::move(batchOutputs));
    }

    // Synchronize the cuda stream
    checkCudaErrorCode(cudaStreamSynchronize(inferenceCudaStream));
    checkCudaErrorCode(cudaStreamDestroy(inferenceCudaStream));
    return true;
}
```